# psycopg2 installation Error in virtualenv(django_project)

Tags: python-3.x, django, psycopg2, psql

Building a simple blog project with django
Problem happened when deployment part.
Help me to get rid of this situation
advance Tnx

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: '/home/sium/Documents/django/sample (another copy)/bin/python' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-reak32wu/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-reak32wu/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-onebo_jx
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-reak32wu/psycopg2/
  Complete output (40 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/sium/Documents/django/sample (another copy)/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
  In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:28:
  ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
     36 | #include <libpq-fe.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  
  It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
  
  You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
  If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
  required for the build and try again.
  
  For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
  <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
  
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for psycopg2 which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: '/home/sium/Documents/django/sample (another copy)/bin/python' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-reak32wu/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-reak32wu/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-3p965hep/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '/home/sium/Documents/django/sample (another copy)/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2'
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-reak32wu/psycopg2/
    Complete output (40 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/sium/Documents/django/sample (another copy)/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:28:
    ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
       36 | #include <libpq-fe.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    
    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
    
    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: '/home/sium/Documents/django/sample (another copy)/bin/python' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-reak32wu/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-reak32wu/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-3p965hep/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '/home/sium/Documents/django/sample (another copy)/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2' Check the logs for full command output.
```

> At first I install psycopg2-binary this is not recommended for host in Heroku.
> So I uninstall it via pip, then try to install

```
pip3 install  psycopg2
```

***But every time comes up this Error***
*here is all package list which i installed so far for this project*

```
asgiref==3.2.10
Django==3.1.1
django-taggit==1.2.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
```

Comment: ***sorry guys for bothering you  , finally I can solve the error,thats something like -the code don't work, "why?", and work then the question will be the same "why it is work" ***

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what happened for this question, but I ran into this recently in my CI/CD process on GH Actions.

Long story short, psycopg2 2.8.6 is not compatible with python:3.8.2-alpine. (tested by reverting to 2.8.5)

I updated my python image to 3.8.5 and it then does work with pwycopg2 2.8.6.

Supposedly this is why some [people use psycopg2-binary](https://twitter.com/carltongibson/status/1251051494721441796)

But I've never used that before and I've never had a problem until now, specifically on Alpine.